# Use external Jquery in Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use the typeahead code(external file, country.js)

```
var $input = $("#input-search_address");
$input.typeahead({source:['United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Germany','China']});
```

But this code above, it is a separate file, not in the same jsp, it is in the country.js file. When I use the same code, however in jsp I do this:

```
  <script>
   var $input = $("#input-country");
    $input.typeahead({source:['United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Germany','China']});
  </script>
```

What about my input,

```
<input type="text" id="input-country" class="input" placeholder="Country">
```

In other words, I use the same code in country.js does not work, and when I put the same code in jsp, just adding   works.

I wanted typeahead to work without being in jsp, but in country.js

I use to import .js:

```
<script src="javascript/country.js" type="text"></script>
```

Any tips, help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoM7w.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you waiting for DOM to be ready?

Answer (score 0):

In your `country.js` file, wait for the page to be ready first:

```
$(function() {
  // now write your code
});
```

Comment: Yes, i use;  var $input = $("#input-search_address");
$input.typeahead({source:['United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Germany','China']});

Answer (score 0):

Any other tips? The reference to the other file, country.js, is being successfully made. But the code does not work.